# Cannot read property 'state' of undefined in react-native context api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I'm trying to context api in my ract-native app. But i'm getting this error.
**TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined.** What is wrong my code?

**appContext.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

class AppProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            number: 10,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return 
        (
            <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AppContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default AppProvider;
```

**homeScreen.js**

```
import { AppContext } from './appContext';
<AppContext.Consumer>
    {(context) => context.number}
</AppContext.Consumer>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not using your `AppProvider` component anywhere in your App. Try like this:

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();

class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      number: 10,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppProvider>
        <AppContext.Consumer>
          {context => context.number}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
      </AppProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

`AppProvider` is merely a standard component here. It renders the context's `Provider` and that one gets some children. So, you should use this `AppProvider` component somewhere in your app and pass a child with a `Consumer`.

If you want to keep your context in a separate file it would be like this:

**Context and provider component**

```
import React from "react";

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      number: 1745,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default AppProvider;
```

**Main component**

```
import React from "react";
import AppProvider, { AppContext } from "./AppProvider";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppProvider>
        <AppContext.Consumer>
          {context => context.number}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
      </AppProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer. I was trying 2 hours. But why we imported with curly braces. **{ AppContext }**. it isn't work.

Comment: You are welcome. In my example, `AppContext` is a named export. This is why I used here with curlies. In that file, our default export is `AppProvider`. Actually, it should work with this setup.

Comment: I'm sory. I made a mistake another import component. It is working now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Again, you are welcome my "hemşehri" :) If my answer helped you consider accepting it, please. So it can be closed in this way.